# GnuPG inner workings (encryption scheme, mode of operation, ciphers)

Tags: gnupg

I have some questions concerning how GnuPG operates when encrypting and signing messages.

By default:

- Which cipher and mode-of-operation is used for symmetric encryption?
- What encryption scheme is used for the encryption of the session key?
- Which hash function and signature scheme is used in a signed message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GnuPG implements the [OpenPGP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) which contains most of the answers you are looking after. Namely:

- [Symmetric encryption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.7) uses **CFB mode** (with full-block feedback). Supported block ciphers are **IDEA**, **CAST5**, **3DES**, **Blowfish**, **AES** and **Twofish**. Other algorithms may be supported in the future.
- The session key is [encrypted with the recipient's public key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1), using whatever algorithm is appropriate for the used key type. OpenPGP supports **RSA** and **ElGamal**. There is room for other algorithms but the standard mandates only these two.
- [Signatures](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2) use an algorithm which depends on the signer's key type; the standard describes formats for **RSA** and **DSA**. There again, there is room for other future algorithms. The hash function used with the signature algorithm can be **MD5**, **RIPEMD-160**, **SHA-1**, **SHA-224**, **SHA-256**, **SHA-384** or **SHA-512**.

See [section 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9) for the lists of supported algorithms.

[GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) implements *most* of the above; some of the algorithms may be absent, depending on how it was compiled. Most recent pre-compiled GnuPG packages will lack support for the [IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm) block cipher (because it was patented until quite recently), but will include support for the block cipher [Camellia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_%28cipher%29) in addition to the standard ones (despite the fact that Camellia *is* patented, but available under a royalty-free license).